# Reactjs setState issue

Tags: reactjs

In react, I'm storing the data in state. The issue is that I'm able to store and read the state within the function. But if I try to read it in render() method, I'm not able to read the state. Here is the below code :

```
import Opt from './GenerateData.jsx';

constructor(props) {
    this.state = {
        options : ""
    }

    this.handleOptions = this.handleOptions.bind(this);
} 

handleOptions(params) {
    this.setState({
        options: params
    });

    // here it will print the state value
    console.log(this.state.options)
}
```

// but it won't print it here..

```
render() {
    return (

        <Opt handleOptions={this.handleOptions.bind(this)} />
        ...
        ...
        <FilterOpts name="optionSelection" data={this.state.options} />
    )
}
```

**In GenerateData.jsx**

```
class GenerateData extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        var d = [1,2,3,4];
        this.props.handleOptions(d);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div></div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: ideally it should be the other way round

Comment: Does it print if you supply the state via the constructor?

Comment: yes it's able to print if I directly send it from constructor

Comment: `handleOptions ` never called in this code sample.

Comment: If handleOptions never called, then how come it's able to store the handleOptions paramater in state and print it there ?

Comment: @B77 Idk. You tell us how you want to call this function. Finally it's your code. The fact is **`handleOptions` is never called in code you have provided**

Comment: from where is the handleOptions function called,

Comment: Guys I've updated the code.. handleOptions I'm calling from other component when I get the data..

Comment: Look in your `<FilterOpts>` component. Most likely the error is in there, since the component you show does nothing with `this.state.options` directly in its `render` method.

Answer (score -1):

React setState() is asynchronous. It does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a pending state transition.

You can try this code to log the updated state.

```
handleOptions(params) {
    this.setState({
            options: params
        }, () => {console.log(this.state.options);}
    );     
}
```